# Php query only performing one time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP query which sends the messages to the people according to the time in MySQL database :if it is 8:00 pm it will send the message at 8:00 pm to those people who have that time in the database.The problem i'm having is that my php query is only sending the message to the first person in the database only it isn't looking at other users I have in my database. I am using now sms gateway in sending the message.
Here is my php:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hospital";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM uap";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " - Drug time: " . $row["drug1morning"]. "<br>";


        $hour = date('G');
        $min =date('i');
        $sec =date('sa');
        if ($hour == $row["drug1morning"]  && $min == 00 && $sec == 03 )  {

            function SendSMS ($host, $port, $username, $password, $phoneNoRecip, $msgText) {

                $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
                if (!$fp) {
                    echo "errno: $errno \n";
                    echo "errstr: $errstr\n";
                    return $result;
                }

                fwrite($fp, "GET /?Phone=" . rawurlencode($phoneNoRecip) . "&Text=" . rawurlencode($msgText) . " HTTP/1.0\n");
                if ($username != "") {
                    $auth = $username . ":" . $password;
                    $auth = base64_encode($auth);
                    fwrite($fp, "Authorization: Basic " . $auth . "\n");
                }
                fwrite($fp, "\n");

                $res = "";

                while(!feof($fp)) {
                    $res .= fread($fp,1);
                }
                fclose($fp);

                return $res;
            }

            $x   = SendSMS("127.0.0.1", 8800, "admin", "admin", $row["phonenumber"], "Hey there !!!!");
            echo $x;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a function inside an "if" block?

Comment: Take the SendSMS function outside the loop. It's running once because you are running into an error when it try's to define that function again. Maybe errors are turned off and you arn't seeing it.

Comment: if I remove the send sms function insinde the "if" block then the SendSMS function will run infinitely.

Comment: Danny can you tell me how I can solve it by removing the while loop

Comment: It only runs when it is called and it will stop after it processes the code inside the function as long as it doesn't call itself and can an infinite loop.

Comment: Select the function SendSMS ($host, $port, $username, $password, $phoneNoRecip, $msgText) {  ALL THE CODE INSIDE }. Cut and paste it above $servername. It doesn't have to be there but just to test it. That's all you don't need to do anything else just "move" that function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will never help anyone else. Enable errors and debug a little.

Comment: Instead of writing your own HTTP library, why not use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)? It's built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` the function was getting defined multiple time. Just move it out and if will works.

Proper way:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //old code
    }
}
function SendSMS (...) {
}
```

If you are really need to put inside, then avoid multiple declaration:

```
if (!function_exists('SendSMS')) {
    function SendSMS (...) {
    }
}
```